# Checking if the site I'm following has newsfeed enabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

Problem:
I want to fetch all the sites that I'm following but want to eliminate those that don't have newsfeed/site feed enabled.

There is a REST endpoint to fetch all the sites that I'm following:

`/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=4)`

This rest endpoint gives me all the sites that I am following but doesn't tell me anything about if that site has newsfeed or not.

So I have to make another REST call to this one:

`/_api/web/features/getById(guid'15a572c6-e545-4d32-897a-bab6f5846e18')`

The problem is that I am not in SharePoint context. I am doing all this in an AngularJS app and when I try to access this endpoint, I get an exception:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load /_api/web/features/getById(guid'15a572c6-e545-4d32-897a-bab6f5846e18'). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any better way to deal with this? Do I need to set a header in my REST call to not get this cross domain exception?

Thanks

Comment: Try:
executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(webUrl);
executor.executeAsync and then use url as"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/features...

Comment: Hey Aveenav, As I mentioned I am doing this in angularjs app so i don't have SharePoint context. The solution you proposed works well if i am building sharepoint hosted apps for example.

Answer (score 0):

You check the following links for angualarJS with sharepoint.

http://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/getting-list-data-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-and-angular-js/

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/12/votr-part-5-angularjs-crud-restful-apis.html

Hope this helps.